# can you make postgres sql more efficient

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, psycopg2

I am trying to learn some postgres skills to help me building my flask application and I really care about performance but I faced some issues.

**I have the following table (`Sessions`) in postgres:**

| SessionID | Other columns | Statics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BDzQDeGr | * | {"excludedOptions": {"questID": ["optID", "optID2"]}} |

**Note: Statics is a jsonb.**

I wanted to execute a query that append `optID` to `"Statics"->'excludedOptions'->'questID'` jsonb array if `questID` exists else append `questID` to `excludedOptions` that has `["optID"]` as value.
I spent my last 4 days trying to do that with one query, And finally I did it ...

```
WITH ex AS 
(
    SELECT "Statics" -> 'excludedOptions' 
    FROM "Sessions" 
    WHERE "SessionID" = '{data["sessionId"]}'
)
UPDATE "Sessions" 
SET "Statics" = jsonb_set(
    "Statics", 
    ARRAY['excludedOptions', '{data["questionId"]}'], 
    array_to_json(array_remove((
        SELECT
            ARRAY['{data["answerId"]}'] || coalesce((
            SELECT
                jsonb_array_to_text_array((
                    SELECT value 
                    FROM jsonb_each(( SELECT ex.* FROM ex)) 
                    WHERE key = '{data["questionId"]}'
                ))
            ), null)
    ), null))::jsonb, 
    TRUE
) WHERE "SessionID" = '{data["sessionId"]}'
```

**NOTE: SQL above is a python f-string**

but when I measured the executing time it was about 300-600ms witch is a lot of time for this simple operation.
I wanted it to be one query cz somehow I believe that one query is better :).

#### Can you help me making this query faster?

#### Would creating a function make it faster? or simpler?

**Thank you for spending a little of your time for me**

### UPDATE

Table Schema:

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | numeric(16,0) |  | not null |  | main |  |  |
| SessionID | character varying(8) |  | not null |  | extended |  |  |
| Title | text |  | not null |  | extended |  |  |
| Type | text |  | not null |  | extended |  |  |
| Source | text |  | not null |  | extended |  |  |
| Questions | character(6)[] |  | not null |  | extended |  |  |
| Skipped | character(6)[] |  |  | '{}'::bpchar[] | extended |  |  |
| Answered | json |  |  | '{}'::json | extended |  |  |
| UsedHints | character(6)[] |  |  | '{}'::bpchar[] | extended |  |  |
| FinalResult | smallint |  |  | 0 | plain |  |  |
| Statics | jsonb |  |  | '{"timer":{}, "excludedOptions":{}}'::json | extended |  |  |
| Marked | character(6)[] |  |  | '{}'::bpchar[] | extended |  |  |
| Time | integer |  | not null | 0 | plain |  |  |

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Seq Scan on "Sessions"  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=1 width=894) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.037 ms
Execution Time: 0.030 ms
```

Comment: Please show us your table schema *including the indexes*. `\d+ Sessions` in psql should do it. Also show us the [`explain analyze`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) on the query. Please tell us the purpose of this table, the schema can probably be improved; in particular the jsonb column might be better done with traditional SQL. Note: avoid quoting every identifier, it forces them to be case-sensitive. `update sessions` not `update "Sessions"`.

Comment: `WHERE "SessionID" = '{data["sessionId"]}'` is suspect. That is checking that the `SessionID` column is equal to *the string* `{data["sessionId"]}`.

Comment: Sorry it's for python and `data["questionId"]` is an identifier for question, Like `"Tg5d74"`

Comment: Your query is not using the Python dict `data`. It is the literal string `data["questionId"]`. And, again, we need to see your schema, indexes, and please tell us the purpose of the table.

Comment: I entered the f-string data, python will replace all of that with the value and it's working without any errors but very slow

Comment: Make that clear in your question, please.

Comment: Your execution time is 0.030 ms. There's no data in the table. The `explain analyze` is useless without data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table has no indexes, so Postgresql must scan the whole table to find anything. That's what a "Seq Scan" is. You need to add some [indexes](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_index.asp) to avoid table scans and make queries efficient.

Since you're checking `WHERE "SessionID" = ...` an index on SessionID would allow Postgres to find all matching rows without having to scan the whole table.

See [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) for more about SQL performance tuning and indexes.

Other notes:

1. Don't use `char`, [there is no benefit and many drawbacks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html). Use `varchar` or `text`.
2. While arrays and JSON seem like they save a lot of effort, they're very, very easy to abuse. There's no short-cut around good schema design. Arrays should be limited to very simple lists, and JSON for when you need to store truly arbitrary data. All of your arrays and JSON should probably be replaced with traditional columns and [join tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).
3. Store time as a [timestamp or other date/time type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), not an integer.
4. Don't use the `json` type. [`jsonb` is more efficient](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). Especially don't mix `json` and `jsonb`, it just invites confusion.
5. `numeric(16,0)` is an odd choice for a primary key. A simple `bigint` will use less space, be more efficient, and store a larger number. PostgreSQL even provides the convenient [`bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) type for auto-incrementing primary keys.
6. Don't quote table and column names (identifiers) unless necessary to resolve ambiguities. SQL identifiers are normally case-insensitive, but quoting makes them case-sensitive which will lead to problems.
7. Don't use SQL keywords for column names. For example, `time`. Use the "at" and "on" conventions for timestamps and dates. For example, `created_at` or `created_on`.

Comment: Is it fine using `session_id`  as column name?

Comment: @ELAi Yes, or sessionID if you prefer CamelCase. You only need to avoid [SQL and Postgres keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: postgres is case-sensitive and using upper case in tables or columns name will force me to double quote the names each time I use them, am I right? (The 6th note)

Comment: @ELAi No, Postgres identifiers are case-insensitive. `select sessionid from sessions` will work fine. It's only when you quote them that they become case-sensitive. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dc41b5770078037c5cf1b0fd135f7149).

Comment: [Don't use serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)  though - use an `identity` column instead.

Answer (score 1):

The performance hints given Schwern are absolutely valid. However, your UPDATE statement can be simplified drastically - at least if I understood your question correctly.

```
update sessions
   set statistics =
         case 
           when statistics -> 'excludedOptions' ? 'questID' 
             then jsonb_set(statistics, '{excludedOptions,questID}', (statistics #> '{excludedOptions,questID}') || '["newOptId"]') 
           else 
             jsonb_set(statistics, '{excludedOptions}', '{"questID": ["newOptId"]}') 
          end
where session_id = ....;
```

If there is a a key `questID` within the `excludedOptions` then this will append the string value `"newOptId"` to that array. If there is no key `questID` it will be created with a single-element array as its value.

There is no need for a CTE or unnesting and aggregating the array for `questID`

`sessions.session_id` should have an index to make this fast.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dcb7aae8781466f2ef8033565b36b818)

Comment: I faced an issue, when I insert another `questID` it deletes the previous ids :)

Comment: I solved it by editing `else` statement to be `jsonb_set(statics, '{excludedOptions, questID}', '["newOptId"]') `